# How to plot color bands with specific width in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, data-visualization

My data contains, bands of three colors each.
Each band contains percentage of that color.
And finally each set of color has a "value" against which I would like to plot on a graph.
Hence to summarize the motive:
*I need to plot a set of three colors that can show the percentage contribution of the color and its metric "value"*

This is an image of ideal plot I am trying to plot:

[image: image1]

I would like to plot this chart in matplotlib, but I found no way to plot this graph or maybe I dint look properly.
Couldnt find a relavent post to this.

Here is my sample data

| Colour_Code1 | Percentage_of_colour1_present | Colour_Code2 | Percentage_of_colour2_present | Colour_Code3 | Percentage_of_colour3_present | Parameter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (234,234,234) | 60% | (211,211,211) | 30% | (78,23,34) | 10% | 0.45 |
| (234,231,231) | 50% | (211,21,21) | 30% | (25,23,34) | 20% | 0.6 |

The "value" is the parameter that I would like to plot against.

Comment: Could you please add representative sample data. It isn't clear what you mean by 'percentage of a colour'? Also, how is the bar length determined? Are there 3 values for each colour?

Comment: Maybe a [Matplotlib bar chart](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html) or even a [Matplotlib broken bar chart](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/broken_barh.html) is the type of graph you are looking for?